# My javascript not woriking on ajax loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple html page with jquery for updating the contents of the different menu items from a php script on my server but the scripts written for the ajax loaded elements are not working.
 how do i correct this.
please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) aka, we can't help you unless you post your code.

Comment: Possibly the case of [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to apply your code for elements that do not yet exist in your document and that are created dynamically.
If you're using jQuery, read this: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah thats what i taught was the problem but i actually called the functions onload of those very elements an it didn't still work

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()` method, when generating elements dynamically..

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callbackFfunction(){

});
```

**Example**

```
$(document).on('click','button.yellow-button', function(e){

});
```

Let me know if it not works.